# Invert chosen options in multiple select boxes by JQuery does not act when putting a div around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

first please excuse my english, I'm not a native speaker.
I have a really weird problem.
I have these two multiple select boxes:

```
<select id="leftEntities" class="width390px" multiple="multiple" size="8">
   <option value="1">Option A</option>
   <option value="2">Option B</option>
</select>

<select id="rightEntities" class="width390px" multiple="multiple" size="8">
   <option value="1">Option C</option>
   <option value="2">Option D</option>
</select>
```

and this button which should perform an invert of the selected options.

```
<button id="invert" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></button>
```

This is the JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#invert').click(function() {
   SWAPLIST.invert($(this).parent().find('select'));
   });
});

var SWAPLIST = {};
SWAPLIST.invert = function(list) {
   $(list)
   .children()
   .prop('selected', function(i, selected) {
      return !selected;
   });
}
```

The problem is that this works like it should work, when there's no div container around the button, but if I put one around it, it does not work anymore.

In other words, this is what not works:

```
<div class="sometestclass">
   <button id="invert" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: if $(this).parent() is not the parent of the selects then it will of course not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TRy
http://jsfiddle.net/5jb3P/

you cannot select parent as parent is now `<div>`

So you should acess it by either select or by id of elements

like

```
$('select') or $('#leftEntities,#rightEntities')
```

Comment: $('leftEntities') will not select anything

Answer (score 3):

if `$(this).parent()` is not the parent of the selects then it will not work

Try this instead

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NhFSa/)

```
SWAPLIST.invert($("select.width390px"));
```

or

```
SWAPLIST.invert($("select[id$='Entities']"));
```

Full solution

```
$(function(){
  $('#invert').on("click",function() {
    SWAPLIST.invert($("select[id$='Entities']"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `$(this).parent()` points to this `DIV`. Use `$(this).parent().parent()` or some other selector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem behind this is : you have used : `$(this).parent()`. In many situations, that will not compute to what you want and as such it will lead to failure .

However, it's better use the `select classes` that you are adding in html mark up like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#invert').click(function() {
       console.log($("select.width390px"));
       //SWAPLIST.invert($(this).parent().find('select'));
       SWAPLIST.invert($("select.width390px"));
   });
});
```

Find the working fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/2ceUC/1/

Comment: @mplungjan : Ahh, sorry about that, did not see your post before . Just typed in the solution that came to my mind. Sorry !

Answer (score 0):

With `$(this)` you take the button. Then with `parent()` you go to the parent. Then with `find()`, you are looking for some element.

However, if there is a `div` around the `button`, the parent will be the `div`. And starting there, the `find` will fail.

Comment: yes , you have given a good explanation of what's wrong, but you need to give an alternative solution as well, since the OP is looking for that .

Comment: The question contains a problem. And I explained why it occured. For giving an approriate solution, I need more information. It might be: select via the ids, select all selects, navigate via parent().parent(), etc. After having understood the reason for the problem, finding a suitable solution should be much easier.